# In database create ,update, drop view

Tags: mysql, database

[image: This is the database relation]

I create ‘**Supplier_Country**’ view.
How to alter  ‘**Supplier_Country**’ view to check whether the same product is 
supplied by different suppliers?

View:

```
CREATE VIEW Supplier_Countryt AS 
    SELECT supplier.ContactName, supplier.Country, product.ProductName 
    FROM supplier, product 
    WHERE supplier.Id = product.Id 
    ORDER BY ContactName ASC;
```

Comment: You might want to provide us with the query from your view and what you've tried or how you understand it.

Comment: Please include the expected output and your attempt to create the view

Comment: ``CREATE VIEW Supplier_Countryt AS
 SELECT supplier.ContactName,supplier.Country,product.ProductName
 FROM supplier,product
 WHERE supplier.Id =product.Id
 ORDER BY ContactName ASC; `` this is my quer for crteating view

Comment: I think next i use to some condition but i cannot how to use it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `WHERE supplier.Id = product.Supplierid` for the join?

Comment: Why are you creating a VIEW?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your diagram, you can't.
Your Product/Supplier tables have a One-To-Many relationship with one supplier supplying many products, but each product only having one supplier (`SupplierId`) in your diagram.

Create a link table that joins `Supplier` to `Product` in a Many-To-Many relationship (`ProductId` and `SupplierId`).

You can then specify the same product id to many suppliers and run your query from that link table.